# Remove specifc characters from string (REGEX)

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to get part of a string that is between parenthesis followed by four digits using REGEX like this:

```
data = "lorem ipsum lorem lorem ipsum ipsum lot lorem lot ipsum (2020/4568921-0) gfdgf"

def func_proc(line):
    nr = ''.join(map(str, (re.findall(r"\([0-9]{4}.*?\)", line))))
    if not nr:
        return 0
    else:
        return nr

print(func_proc(data))
```

I'm getting "(2020/4568921-0)" as the result instead of the needed "2020/4568921-0".

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to do. Just remove parentheses?

Comment: `(?<=\()[0-9]{4}.*?(?=\))`

Comment: I'm sorry, I've not made it clear. Yes, I want just what's inside the parentheses, but not the parenthesis symbol itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the string between the ().

```
import re

data = "lorem ipsum lorem lorem ipsum ipsum lot lorem lot ipsum (2020/4568921-0) gfdgf"

def func_proc(line):
    nr = ''.join(map(str, re.findall(r"\(([0-9]{4}.*?)\)", line)))
    if not nr:
        return 0
    else:
        return nr

print(func_proc(data))
```

If there are multiple results then you can return the first like this.

```
import re

data = "lorem ipsum lorem lorem ipsum ipsum lot lorem lot ipsum (2020/4568921-0) gfdgf (2020/4568921-0)"

def func_proc(line):
    nr =re.findall(r"\(([0-9]{4}.*?)\)", line)
    if not nr:
        return 0
    else:
        return nr[0]

print(func_proc(data))
```

Comment: Suppose I have more than one occurrence of these sequences, such as 2020/456789 and 2019/0054789 in the same string, and I would like to get only the first one. How can I manage to do that?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Would the other 'sequences' also be enclosed in ()?

Comment: I mean, If in the same string I have something like: data = "lorem ipsum lorem lorem ipsum ipsum lot lorem lot ipsum (2020/4568921-0) gfdgf (2010/2225698)" and I would like to get the first group only, e.g., 2020/4568921-0 and not the last one, e.g., 2010/2225698)

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to return the first match.